# Jquery Mobile update page DOM before show

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, dom

How do i populate data to another page before displaying it? I am trying to update the DOM of another page i will load before displaying it to the user. I need to make sure that the data in its DOM is already prepared before showing the page.

Here's my scenario :

I have 2 pages : login.html and profile.html

login.html is the first page to be seen by the user and contains login ui and functionality which is having api calls using ajax after clicking the login button

This my javascript code if user click login button in login.html file

```
// user clicks login button, execute this code
$.ajax({
        url: app.base_url + "/user/login",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params,
        success : function(result) {
             if (result.success) { // if login successful
                   getUserData();
             }
        }
});

function getUserData() {
   $.ajax({
        url: app.base_url + "/user/getProfilePageInfo",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params,
        success : function(result) {
             if (result.total > 0) { // if there is data retrieved, continue code below

                  // update firstname and lastname in DOM of profile.html
                  $("p.firstname").html(result.firstname); // result.firstname = John
                  $("p.lastname").html(result.lastname);  // result.lastname = Doe

                  // change page to profile.html
                  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "profile.html", { transition: "fade" });
             }
        }
   });

}
```

This is the summary code of my profile.html file

```
<div id="profilepage" class="container" data-role="page">
   <p class="firstname">Default Firstname</p>
   <p class="lastname">Default Lastname</p>
</div>
```

The result of this is the profile.html is displayed but 'Default Firstname' & 'Default Lastname' is still shown. It should be John Doe.

I would be happy for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could pass the data to the next page as an option and then retrieve it in there.

Here's a good writeup.
http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/passing-parameters-between-pages-multi-page-model/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `pagebeforeshow` to apply what you want to do before the page will show.

Check the API : http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/ Take care, "The triggering of this event is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0. It will no longer be triggered in 1.5.0."

But it works for me I use it a lot.

I'm not sure that is what you're looking for. Hopping that this can help you.